# Change Android publish market account with other email adderess

Tags: android, google-play

Does anyone know is it possible to change android market publish account with other email address? Actually I purchase android market account on my personnel email & now I want to share credential with my manager. Is it possible I can exchange publish account with other email address without purchase new publish account ( for other email ) ?
Please help if anybody knows.
Thanks,

Comment: The best place to discuss your query is [Google Support](http://support.google.com/accounts/?hl=en-GB), I don't see any reason why we can't ask help for this, after all, we paid for our developer's account. This is the responsibility that Google should take for paid service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain no, this cannot be done.  Your android market's publishing account is tied to your Google account.

Sorry, but I'm fairly certain you are gonna have to cough up 25 bucks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply purchase another account because you have no way of migrating your existing apps to the new account. Luckily google has now provided (a really odd) way to change the email of your account -> http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139626 . I cannot say how long it will take, as I am currently waiting 3 days and still no response...

EDIT: the migration works, and you get back the fee you paid for the first account (the one you are migrating from). it takes a while though...

Comment: I'm really impressed that Google finally allows a developer to migrate to another account, it seemed impossible before. @stoilkov  But when they moved your apps to the new account, did they save your apps ratings, reviews, positions on site, etc? I mean if your app loses its rating, it's a pretty useless feature. Because your place on Google Play site depends on ratings, so as your earnings, I think.

Comment: ratings and reviews - yes. i am not sure about the other stuff.